# How to count the no. of occurrence of characters in a column input of CSV?

Tags: python, string, csv, count

I have a CSV file (converted from Excel), with one of its column of strings I'm interested in. The strings (around 4000 of them) are made up of different lengths ranging from 4 chars to 22 chars, but only consisted of 4 characters (A, B, C or D).

I want to count the number of occurrences of each of the 4 chars (A, B, C or D) in each position of the strings.

For example, consider the following strings:

```
ABBA, CDABB, AAAAAA
```

Then, in the first position of each string, A occurred twice and C occurred once. In the 6th position of each string, A occurred once.

So far, I thought of steps to solve this problem:

1. Sort the strings alphabetically (A, B, C then D)
2. Find the index of the first B that occurred (= no. of As minus 1)
3. Repeat list.find for C and D.
4. Store the values of no. Of occurrences of A, B, C, D in the first position in some array.
5. Remove the first letter of each string (using string.lstrip()). Repeat the above.

Either that or just iterate and count the number of occurrences of letters in the nth position and then perform string.lstrip() to remove that letter and repeat iteration.

However, I am not sure how to manipulate the strings within the CSV file, anyone has any tips?

Comment: It would help if you added a complete sample input and output to your question, along with any Python you have written so far to solve it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The only question you're formulating (last line) has nothing to do with counting.

Comment: I don't actually know how to start writing the code, because I don't know how to manipulate CSV files... so would appreciate some help (to start solving the problem at least).

Comment: Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read the CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

counts = Counter()
for line in data:
    counts.update(list(enumerate(line, start=1)))

# count of letter 'o' in the 3rd column:
print(counts[(3, 'o')])
print(counts)

# 2
# Counter({
#   (1, 'f'): 2, (2, 'o'): 2, (3, 'o'): 2, (5, 'a'): 1, 
#   (6, 'r'): 1, (3, 'r'): 1, (1, 'b'): 1, (2, 'a'): 1, 
#   (4, 'b'): 1
# })
```

Comment: Will try it! :) Thx!

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

x = ["ABBA", "CDABB", "AAAAAA"]
Counter(itertools.chain(*[zip(y, enumerate(1, len(y)+1)) for y in x]))

Counter({('A', 1): 2, ('A', 4): 2, ('A', 3): 2, ('B', 2): 1, ('B', 3): 1, ('B', 4): 1, ('C', 1): 1, ('A', 6): 1, ('A', 5): 1, ('D', 2): 1, ('A', 2): 1, ('B', 5): 1})
```

`[zip(y, range(1, len(y)+1)) for y in x]` - create pairs of (A, 0), (B, 1), etc. by the position for each element in x. So we get -

```
[[('A', 0), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('A', 3)], [('C', 0), ('D', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 4)], [('A', 0), ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('A', 4), ('A', 5)]]
```

chain - chain all those lists to one lists and Counter is an constructor of the Counter class which is actually a dictionary which counts how many times each values appears.

You can use https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html to read data from csv file

Comment: Could you explain the different lines of your code please? Thx!

Comment: you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `enumerate` in your answer - much more descriptive in my opinion and should be faster than index arithmetics

Comment: Wow, great method thanks! Will try it ...

Comment: I acually transferred the above code (using the small example of 3 strings I gave) into iPython, and received an error message stating: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. The error seems to be directed at the "Counter(itertools.chain(*[zip(y, enumerate(1, len(y)+1)) for y in x]))" of the code.

Comment: Since I don't have your exact input I advice you to break this line with multiple commands into several lines and check what issues the error.